# I'm trying to run the Phalcon Application. Getting this IndexController handler class error

Tags: phalcon

I'm trying to run the Phalcon Application. Getting this IndexController handler class error. Here is my controller.

```
define('PHALCONSTART', microtime(true));
define('PROJECT_PATH', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/');
use Phalcon\Mvc\Application,
    Phalcon\Loader;
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Dublin');
require_once PROJECT_PATH . 'apps/bootstrap.php';

$loader = new Loader();

$loader->registerNamespaces([
    'Apps\Commons\Models' => PROJECT_PATH . 'apps/commons/models/',
    'Library'             => PROJECT_PATH . 'library/'
]);

$loader->registerClasses([
    'Apps\Commons\AbstractModule' => PROJECT_PATH . 'apps/commons/AbstractModule.php',
]);

$loader->register();

/**
 * Include services
 */
require PROJECT_PATH . 'config/services.php';
require PROJECT_PATH . 'config/repos.php';

/**
 * Handle the request
 */
$application = new Application();

/**
 * Assign the DI
 *
 * @var Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault $di
 */

$application->setDI($di);
//$application->useImplicitView(false);

/**
 * Register application modules
 */
$modules = [];

foreach ($config->modules as $index => $modul)
{
    $modules[$index] = [
        'className' => $modul->className,
        'path'      => $modul->dir . 'Module.php'
    ];
}

$application->registerModules($modules);
require PROJECT_PATH . 'config/function.php';
$response = $application->handle();

$response->send();
```

I'm getting this error no matter what I do. Can't find the solution anywhere.I attached the screenshot of the error I'm getting.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher\Exception: Apps\Members\Controllers\IndexController handler class cannot be loaded in C:\xampp7126\htdocs\find-us-local\public\index.php:86 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher->_throwDispatchException('Apps\Members\Co...', 2) #1 [internal function]: Phalcon\Dispatcher->dispatch() #2 C:\xampp7126\htdocs\find-us-local\public\index.php(86): Phalcon\Mvc\Application->handle() #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp7126\htdocs\find-us-local\public\index.php on line 86

[See the Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8ilf.png)

**UPDATED: Controller Source Code Added**

Following is controller Source Code

```
namespace Members\Controller;

use Members\Form\Profile;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher;
use User\Model\Content;
use User\Model\SubscriptionItems;
use User\Model\Subscriptions;
use User\Model\Support\SupportticketFollowups;
use User\Model\Users;
use Phalcon\Mvc\View;
use User\Model\UsersNotifications;
use User\Model\Usersocialnetworks;
use User\Model\UsersTraffic;
use User\Model\AuthnetTransactions;
use Hybridauth\Hybridauth;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Exception;
use User\Model\Payments\Paypal\PaypalRecurringTrans;
use User\Model\Support\SupportTickets;
use Apps\Members\Controllers\BaseController;

class IndexController extends BaseController
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize(); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub

        if (!$this->user)
        {
            die();

            return $this->response->redirect(['for' => 'oauth.auth.action', 'action' => 'login'])->send();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return View\Engine\Php
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $one_day_traffic = UsersTraffic::sum([
            'column'     => 'hits',
            'conditions' => 'userid = :userid: AND date >= :date:',
            'bind'       => ['userid' => $this->user_id, 'date' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 days'))]
        ]);


        $seven_day_traffic = UsersTraffic::sum([
            'column'     => 'hits',
            'conditions' => 'userid = :userid: AND date >= :date:',
            'bind'       => ['userid' => $this->user_id, 'date' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-7 days'))]
        ]);

        $thirty_day_traffic = UsersTraffic::sum([
            'column'     => 'hits',
            'conditions' => 'userid = :userid: AND date >= :date:',
            'bind'       => ['userid' => $this->user_id, 'date' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days'))]
        ]);

        $phql      =
            'SELECT date, sum(hits) as sum_hits FROM \User\Model\UsersTraffic WHERE userid = :userid: AND date >= :date: GROUP BY date';
        $query     = $this->modelsManager->createQuery($phql);
        $sums_hits = $query->execute(['userid' => $this->user_id, 'date' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days'))]);
        $_max      = 0;
        $_min      = 0;
        foreach ($sums_hits as $sum)
        {
            if ($_max == 0 AND $_min == 0)
            {
                $_max = $sum->sum_hits;
                $_min = $sum->sum_hits;
            } else
            {
                if ($_max < $sum->sum_hits)
                {
                    $_max = $sum->sum_hits;
                }
                if ($_min > $sum->sum_hits)
                {
                    $_min = $sum->sum_hits;
                }
            }
        }

        $day_traffic_30_min = $_min;
        $day_traffic_30_max = $_max;

        $this->assets->collection('header')
            ->addJs('/javascript/alljs.js', false)
            ->addJs('/javascript/tooltip.js', false)
            ->addJs('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js', false, false)
            ->addJs('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js', false, false);

        $this->view->setVars(compact('one_day_traffic', 'seven_day_traffic', 'thirty_day_traffic', 'day_traffic_30_min', 'day_traffic_30_max'));
    }

    public function dit_basic_infoAction()
    {

    }

    /**
     * @return View
     */
    public function membersSocialAction()
    {
        $go = $this->request->getPost('go');

        if (!empty('go') && $go == 'socialpost')
        {
            $post_title    = $this->request->getPost('post_title', 'string');
            $post_message  = $this->request->getPost('post_message', 'striptags');
            $post_networks = $this->request->getPost('post_networks', null, []);

            /*if (!empty($post_title) && !empty($post_message) && is_array($post_networks))
            {
                // Set a session variable
                $this->session->set("socualposts", compact('post_title', 'post_message', 'post_networks'));

                // Get first record
                $usersocialnetworks = Usersocialnetworks::findFirst($this->filter->sanitize($post_networks[0]), 'int');

                if(!empty($usersocialnetworks))
                {
                    return $this->response->redirect(['for' => 'oauth.hybridauth.index', 'provider' => $usersocialnetworks->network]);
                }
            }*/
        }

        $usersocialnetworks = $this->user->ManySocialnetworks;

        $this->view->setVars(compact('usersocialnetworks'));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function profile_statsgraphAction()
    {
        //Disable the view
        $this->view->disable();

        $userid            = $this->request->get('userid', 'int');
        $content_id        = $this->request->get('content_id', 'int');
        $category_id       = $this->request->get('category_id', 'int');
        $parentcategory_id = $this->request->get('parentcategory_id', 'int');

        return $this->view->getPartial("members/index/profile_statsgraph",
            compact('userid', 'content_id', 'category_id', 'parentcategory_id'));
    }

    /**
     * View all Businesses fro user
     *
     * @return \Phalcon\Http\Response|\Phalcon\Http\ResponseInterface
     */
    public function businessesAction()
    {
        $go = $this->request->get('go');
        $id = $this->request->get('id', 'int', null);

        // If delete content
        if (!empty($go) && $go == 'unclaim' && !empty($id))
        {
            // Get content via ID
            $content = Content::findFirst($id);

            // If not found record
            if (!$content)
            {
                $this->flashSession->error('There is no such record in the database!');
                goto endgo;
            }

            // If this record does not belong to this user
            if ($content->userid != $this->user_id)
            {
                $this->flashSession->error('You can not delete this record! You do not have the rights!');
                goto endgo;
            }

            if (!$content->update([
                'userid'      => 0,
                'profileid'   => 0,
                'plan_id'     => 0,
                'rating'      => 0,
                'views'       => 0,
                'ratingwidth' => 0,
                'featured'    => 0,
                'owner_email' => '',
                'owner_name'  => '',
                'owner_title' => ''
            ])
            )
            {
                if (APPLICATION_ENV == 'development')
                {
                    foreach ($content->getMessages() as $message)
                    {
                        $this->flashSession->error($message . ', ');
                    }
                    goto endgo;
                }

                $this->flashSession->error('An error occurred while deleting. Try again later or contact the administrator!');
                goto endgo;
            } else
            {
                // Set notification for users_notifications table
                $users_notification                       = new UsersNotifications();
                $users_notification->userid               = $this->user_id;
                $users_notification->notification_type    = 'profile_management';
                $users_notification->notification_subject = 'Profile Unclaimed';
                $users_notification->notification_body    =
                    'You have unclaimed a profile: ' . $content->company . ' <Br>' . $content->full_address;
                $users_notification->support_enabled      = 1;
                $users_notification->support_ticketid     = 0;
                if ($users_notification->save() == false)
                {
                    if (APPLICATION_ENV == 'development')
                    {
                        $this->logger->error('Error to handle: ' . implode(', ', $users_notification->getMessages()));
                    }
                }

            }

            $this->flashSession->success('You deleted this item!');

            endgo:

            return $this->response->redirect(['for' => 'members.action', 'action' => 'businesses']);
        }

        end:

        $contents = Content::findByUserid($this->user_id);

        $this->assets->collection('header')
            ->addJs('/javascript/tooltip.js', false)
            ->addJs('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js', false, false)
            ->addJs('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js', false, false)
            ->addJs('/javascript/alljs.js', false);

        $user_id = $this->user_id;

        $this->view->setVars(compact('contents', 'user_id'));
    }

    /**
     * Return script for Business Profile Stats of /members/index page
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function statsgraphAction()
    {
        //Disable the view
        $this->view->setRenderLevel(
            View::LEVEL_ACTION_VIEW
        );

        $count_day = 20;

        $userid = $this->request->get('userid', 'int');
        $rndval = $this->request->get('rndval', 'int');

        $hits_traffic = UsersTraffic::find([
            'userid = :userid: AND date >= :date:',
            'bind' => ['userid' => $userid, 'date' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-' . $count_day . ' days'))],
        ]);

        $hit_sums_by_date  = [];
        $call_sums_by_date = [];
        $months            = [];
        $days              = [];

        for ($day = $count_day; $day >= 0; $day--)
        {
            $date                                                 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-' . $day . ' days'));
            $months[date('Y-m', strtotime('-' . $day . ' days'))] = date('F Y', strtotime('-' . $day . ' days'));
            $hit_sums_by_date[$date]                              = 0;
            $call_sums_by_date[$date]                             = 0;
            $days[$date]                                          = (int)date('j', strtotime('-' . $day . ' days'));
        }

        reset($months);
        $title_text = current($months);
        if (count($months) > 1)
        {

            $title_text .= ' - ' . end($months);
        }

        $days = implode(',', $days);

        foreach ($hits_traffic as $item)
        {
            $hit_sums_by_date[$item->date]  += $item->hits;
            $hit_sums_by_date[$item->date]  += $item->mobilehits;
            $call_sums_by_date[$item->date] += $item->mobilecalls;
            $call_sums_by_date[$item->date] += $item->calls;
        }

        $visitors_sums = implode(',', $hit_sums_by_date);
        $calls_sums    = implode(',', $call_sums_by_date);

        $this->view->visitors_sums = $visitors_sums;
        $this->view->calls_sums    = $calls_sums;
        $this->view->title_text    = $title_text;
        $this->view->days          = $days;

    }

    /**
     * Change User Profile page
     */
    public function profileAction()
    {
        $user = Users::findFirst($this->user_id);

        $user->confirm_email = $this->user->email;

        $post_data = $this->request->getPost();

        /**
         * @var Profile form
         */
        $form = new Profile($user);

        if ($this->request->isPost())
        {
            // If edit profile
            if (!empty($post_data['go']) && $post_data['go'] == 'EDIT')
            {
                if ($this->security->checkToken())
                {
                    if ($form->isValid($post_data))
                    {
                        if (!empty($post_data['new_password']))
                        {
                            $user->password = $this->security->hash($post_data['new_password']);
                        }

                        if ($user->save() == false)
                        {
                            if (APPLICATION_ENV == 'development')
                            {
                                foreach ($user->getMessages() as $message)
                                {
                                    $this->flashSession->error($message . ', ');
                                }
                            } else
                            {
                                $this->flashSession->error('An error occurred while saving! Please try again later or contact the administrator!');
                            }
                        } else
                        {
                            $this->flashSession->success('You have successfully changed your profile!');
                        }
                    }
                } else
                {
                    $this->flashSession->error('CSRF validation failed');
                }
                // edit image for profile
            } elseif (!empty($post_data['go']) && $post_data['go'] == 'upload_image')
            {

                if ($this->request->hasFiles() == true)
                {
                    $baseLocation = PUBLIC_PATH . '/userprofile_images/';

                    // Check directory
                    if (!file_exists($baseLocation))
                    {
                        mkdir($baseLocation, 0777);
                    }

                    // Print the real file names and sizes
                    foreach ($this->request->getUploadedFiles() as $file)
                    {

                        if (in_array($file->getExtension(), ['jpg', 'gif', 'png', 'jpeg']))
                        {
                            if ($file->getSize() < 50000)
                            {
                                $name_file = time() . $this->filter->sanitize($file->getName(), 'string');

                                // delete old images
                                if (file_exists($baseLocation . $user->profile_image))
                                {
                                    unlink($baseLocation . $user->profile_image);
                                }

                                //$user->profile_image = $prev_name . $file->getName();
                                if ($user->update(['profile_image' => $name_file]))
                                {
                                    //Move the file into the application
                                    $file->moveTo($baseLocation . $name_file);

                                    $image = new \Phalcon\Image\Adapter\Gd($baseLocation . $name_file);

                                    $image->resize(
                                        139,
                                        null,
                                        \Phalcon\Image::WIDTH
                                    );

                                    $width   = 139;
                                    $height  = 139;
                                    $offsetX = (($image->getWidth() - $width) / 2);
                                    $offsetY = (($image->getHeight() - $height) / 2);

                                    $image->crop($width, $height, $offsetX, $offsetY);

                                    $image->save($baseLocation . $name_file);

                                    $this->flashSession->success('You have successfully changed your profile image!');
                                } else
                                {

                                    $this->flashSession->error('An error occurred while saving! Please try again later or contact the administrator!');
                                }
                            } else
                            {
                                $this->flashSession->error('The file must not exceed 500 kb');
                            }

                        } else
                        {
                            $this->flashSession->error('The file must be the following format - jpg/gif/png');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $this->assets->collection('header')
            ->addJs('/javascript/tooltip.js', false)
            ->addJs('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js', false, false)
            ->addJs('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js', false, false);

        $this->view->setVars(compact('form'));
    }

    /**
     * @return \Phalcon\Http\Response|\Phalcon\Http\ResponseInterface|string
     */
    public function billingAction()
    {
        $order_item_id = $this->request->get('order_item_id', 'int');
        $get_trans     = $this->request->get('get_trans', 'int');
        $rndval        = $this->request->get('rndval', 'int');
        $go            = $this->request->get('go');
        if (!empty($order_item_id))
        {
            //Disable the view
            $this->view->disable();
            $subscriptions = Subscriptions::findFirst(['order_item_id=:order_item_id:', 'bind' => ['order_item_id' => $order_item_id]]);

            if (!empty($go) && $go == 'cancel_subscr')
            {
                if (!empty($subscriptions) && $subscriptions->update(['an_status' => 'cancelled']))
                {
                    $this->flashSession->success('You have closed a plan!');
                } else
                {

                    if (APPLICATION_ENV == 'development')
                    {
                        foreach ($subscriptions->getMessages() as $message)
                        {
                            $this->flashSession->error($message . ', ');
                        }
                    } else
                    {
                        $this->flashSession->error('An error occurred while closing this plan');
                    }
                }

                return $this->response->redirect(['for' => 'members.action', 'action' => 'billing']);

            } elseif (!empty($get_trans) && !empty($rndval))
            {
                if ($subscriptions)
                {
                    $authnet_transactions = [];
                    $paypal_transactions  = [];
                    if ($subscriptions->pmt_src == 'paypal')
                    {
                        $paypal_transactions = PaypalRecurringTrans::find(['recurring_payment_id=:PP_PROFILEID:', 'bind' => ['PP_PROFILEID' => $subscriptions->PP_PROFILEID]]);
                    } elseif ($subscriptions->pmt_src == 'authnet')
                    {
                        $authnet_transactions = AuthnetTransactions::find(['x_subscription_id=:x_subscription_id:', 'bind' => ['x_subscription_id' => $subscriptions->an_subscr_id]]);
                    }

                    return $this->view->getPartial('members/billing/get_order', compact('subscriptions', 'paypal_transactions', 'authnet_transactions'));
                }
            }
        }

        $this->assets->collection('header')
            ->addJs('/javascript/alljs.js', false)
            ->addJs('/javascript/tooltip.js', false);
    }

    /**
     * @return View
     */
    public function upgradeAction()
    {
        $this->assets->collection('header')
            ->addCss('/css/profile-ful.css', false);
        $add_product_id = $this->request->get('add_product_id', 'striptags', null);

        if (is_null($add_product_id))
        {
            // Get content via ID
            $content = Content::findFirstByProfileid($this->user_id);

            $add_product_id = 'local_dir_premium:' . $content->parentcategory_id . ':' . $content->category_id . ':' . $content->id;
        }

        $this->view->setVars(compact('add_product_id'));
    }

    public function supportAction()
    {
        if (!($this->user_id > 0))
        {
            $this->response->redirect('/');

            return false;
        }
        $id     = $this->dispatcher->getParam('id', 'int', null);
        $type   = $this->dispatcher->getParam('type', 'string', null);
        $_types = ['new', 'closed', 'waiting', 'open'];
        if ($id > 0)
        {
            $ticket = SupportTickets::findFirst($id);
            if (!$ticket OR $ticket->userid != $this->user_id)
            {
                return $this->response->redirect('members/support')->send();
            }
            $is_closed      = false;
            $is_add_message = false;

            if ($this->request->isPost())
            {
                $question  = $this->request->getPost('question', 'striptags', null);
                $btn_close = $this->request->getPost('close', null, null);
                $btn_post  = $this->request->getPost('post', null, null);
                if ($btn_close)
                {
                    $ticket->status = SupportTickets::STATUS_CLOSED;
                    if ($ticket->save() === true)
                    {
                        $is_closed = true;
                    }
                } elseif ($btn_post AND $question)
                {
                    $message            = new SupportticketFollowups();
                    $message->ticket_id = $ticket->id;
                    $message->message   = $question;
                    $message->admin_id  = 0;
                    if ($message->save() === true)
                    {
                        $is_add_message = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            $this->view->ticket         = $ticket;
            $this->view->is_closed      = $is_closed;
            $this->view->is_add_message = $is_add_message;
            $this->view->pick('index/support/view');

            return;
        } elseif (in_array($type, $_types))
        {
            $this->_get_support_type($type);

            return;
        } else
        {
            $tickets             =
                SupportTickets::find(['userid=:userid:', 'bind' => ['userid' => $this->user_id]]);
            $this->view->tickets = $tickets;

            return;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Controller source code?
Before dispatch try to debug loaded namespaces/classes.

Comment: I have added the source code of the controller. How I'm supposed to debug the loaded namespaces/classes?

Comment: You have in dispatcher controller initializing on `Apps\Members\Controllers\IndexController`, but Your class has declaration `Members\Controller\IndexController`

Check Your namespaces and declared paths for Modules/Loaders